# $\int_A f(x,t) \frac{\partial} {\partial t} g(x,t) dx dt = \int_{|x|\leq r}f(x,t) g(x,t) dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lp-spaces

Let $f, g\in C^2(\mathbb R^n \times (0, \infty)).$ Put $A= \{ (x,t)\in \mathbb R^n \times (0, \infty): |x|<r, a<t<b \}$ ($r>0$).

Question:

> Can we expect $$\int_A f(x,t) \frac{\partial} {\partial t} g(x,t) dx dt = \int_{|x|\leq r}f(x,t)  g(x,t) dx$$?

Comment: The way it is written here, this equation cannot be true. For once, the left hand side is a fixed number, while the right hand side is dependent on some $t$. To be more precise: Pick $f\neq 0$ to be smooth, nonnegativ and with compact support and set $g(x,t)=1$. Then the right hand side would be positiv, while the left hand side is zero.